# Regex expression for words with length of even number

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex expression for words with even-numbered length.

For example, the output I want from the list containing the words:
`{"blue", "ah", "sky", "wow", "neat"}` is `{"blue", "ah", "neat}`.

I know that the expression `\w{2}` or `\w{4}` would produce 2-worded or 4-worded words, but what I want is something that could work for all even numbers. I tried using `\w{%2==0}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat 2 word characters as a group between anchors `^` to assert the start and `$` to assert the end of the string, or between word boundaries `\b`

```
^(?:\w{2})+$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zq3mie/1).

```
import re

strings = [
    "blue",
    "ah",
    "sky",
    "wow",
    "neat"
]

for s in strings:
    m = re.match(r"(?:\w{2})+$", s)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Output

```
blue
ah
neat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need no extra validation for the strings in your set, you can simply use

```py
words = {"blue", "ah", "sky", "wow", "neat"}
print( list(w for w in words if len(w) % 2 == 0) )
# => ['ah', 'blue', 'neat']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ku6AWd).

If you want to make sure the words you return are made of letters, you can use

```py
import re
words = {"blue", "ah", "sky", "wow", "neat"}
rx = re.compile(r'(?:[^\W\d_]{2})+')   # For any Unicode letter words
# rx = re.compile(r'(?:[a-zA-Z]{2})+') # For ASCII only letter words
print( [w for w in words if rx.fullmatch(w)] )
# => ['blue', 'ah', 'neat']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/GN5CmI). A `(?:[^\W\d_]{2})+` pattern matches one or more occurrences of any two Unicode letters. Together with `re.fullmatch`, it requires a string to consist of an even amount of letters.